# Unable to send the MSMQ messages through public queue

Tags: c#, windows, model-view-controller, msmq

I am able to send the messages to the MSMQ through private queue.

**C#**

```
   var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machinename\myqueue");
   queue.Send(myMessage, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

[image]

But when I am trying to send the MSMQ messages through public queue.

**C#**

```
   var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machinename\PUBLIC$\myqueue");
   queue.Send(myMessage, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Format name is invalid
```

Please assist in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MSDN docs here ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch1d814t(v=vs.110).aspx

It looks like you don't need "PUBLIC$" in the path for public queues.

So perhaps something like ...

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machinename\myqueue");
```

which appears to be different for private queues.

Micorsoft then goes on to explain that this may work for you ...

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(@".\\myqueue");
```

Assuming the queue is a local one.

Comment: Thanks. I am sending the MSMQ messages to a different computer through IP address.

Comment: Here you go: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues/